# Aggregate the data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that is shown below:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tribble(
  ~category, ~product_id, 
  "A",         10, 
  "B",         20,    
  "C",         30, 
  "A",         10, 
  "A",         10, 
  "B",         20, 
  "C",         30, 
  "A",         10, 
  "A",         10, 
  "B",         20, 
)
```

And now, I want to group it by the "category" variable, keep the "product_id" and add a new variable that counts the categories:

```
  aggregated_data <- tribble(
  ~category, ~product_id, ~numberOfcategory
  "A",         10,       5,
  "B",         20,       3,   
  "C",         30,       2,
)
```

I already got the "numberOfcategory" with this code:

```
data %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  tally(sort=TRUE)
```

But somehow I could not keep the product_id.

Could someone help me to get the dataframe (aggregated_data)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close! Just also group by `product_id` as follows:

```
data %>%
  group_by(category,product_id) %>%
  tally(sort=TRUE)
```